# How to add components in to an existing GUI created by guide?

Tags: user-interface, matlab, matlab-guide

I just created a GUI using guide in MATLAB for a small project I'm working on. I have amongst other things two text fields for *from* and *to* dates. Now I'd like to get rid of them and use a Java date select tool. Of course this is not possible using guide so I need to add them manually.
I've managed to get them to show up by putting this code into my Opening_Fcn,

```
uicomponent(handles, 'style','com.jidesoft.combobox.DateChooserPanel','tag','til2');
```

using [UICOMPONENT](http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/14583-uicomponent-expands-uicontrol-to-all-java-classes).

But even though it shows up I can't access the date select's attributes, for example

```
get(handles.til2)
```

returns

```
??? Reference to non-existent field 'til2'.
```

How can I fix this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Unless you edit the saved GUI figure, the basic `handles` structure will not include your new component by default.

One way to access you component is to store the handle via guidata, by adding the following to your opening function:

```
handles.til2 = uicomponent(handles, 'style','com.jidesoft.combobox.DateChooserPanel','tag','til2');
guidata(hObject,handles)
```

Functions that need to access the handle need the line

```
handles = guidata(hObject)
```

to return the full handles structure that includes the filed `til2`